# Filter by custom field in WordPress admin list

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hoping that someone can help me with this rather frustrating issue:

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields for a custom post type called "customer_reviews" that has 2 custom fields: "cust_rating" (1-5) and "customer_tech" (ACF relationship field that returns 1 ID from another custom post type called "staff_members").

What i want to do is show 2 filter dropdowns in the admin list for "customer_reviews". One should say "Rating" and the other "Technician". The idea is to filter reviews by either x-star rating or technician, or both, meaning that for example, i'd like to show all 4 star reviews that are related to the technician "John Doe" and vice versa. I've researched how to add custom field filters to the admin list and here is my code so far: http://pastebin.com/5reZrEMk

The problem i keep running into is that when i filter by "Rating", i get the correct number of posts with that rating, but if i filter by "Technician" i get an empty list.

Comment: Could you supply some code? How you're creating your custom post types, how you're retrieving the data on your page template, what your ACF's look like, etc.

Comment: Here is how i'm adding my cpt: http://pastebin.com/ViHim5G2. The data on the page template is retrieved via get_posts and a foreach loop so i can use the_field('something'); for each field value like rating etc. My question however pertains only to the admin screen in WordPress, not the front-end.

Comment: Oh ok, my mistake. I completely missed the part about it being in the admin interface.

Comment: The site is full of good stuff: [Add filter menu to admin list of posts (of custom type) to filter posts by custom field values](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45436/12615)

Comment: That's the answer i initially found to start my code for this.

Comment: @blueplasma_dev were you able to find a solution to this problem? I am having similar issue with my site and wondering if anyone has already done this.

Comment: sorry no, there's been no progress with this.